# google-oauth2 + devise :: service.list_user_labels user_id - error - Google::Apis::ClientError: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: ruby, devise, gmail-api, google-api-client, omniauth-google-oauth2

Error - `Google::Apis::ClientError: insufficientPermissions: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

Facing error - at line `result = service.list_user_labels user_id` in dashboards_controller.rb

Following are my files.

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, client_id, client_secret
```

users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    #create user

    if user.present?
      flash[:success] = t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: 'Google'
      sign_in_and_redirect user, event: :authentication
    else
      flash[:alert] = t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.failure', kind: 'Google', reason: "#{auth.info.email} is not authorized."
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

dashboards_controller.rb

```
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets.rb'
require 'google/apis/gmail_v1'
require 'googleauth'

class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def show
        # Initialize the API
        service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
        service.authorization = google_secret.to_authorization
        service.authorization.refresh!
        # Show the user's labels
        user_id = current_user.uid
        result = service.list_user_labels user_id
        puts "Labels:"
        #puts "No labels found" if result.labels.empty?
        #result.labels.each { |label| puts "- #{label.name}" }
  end

  private

      def google_secret
            scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels"

            Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.new(
          { "web" =>
            { "access_token" => current_user.token,
              "refresh_token" => current_user.refresh_token,
              "client_id" => client_id,
              "client_secret" => client_secret,
              "scope" => scope
            }
          }
        )
      end
end
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what scope you added? Also, I'm not sure I understand `The User was getting created, the issue occurred on dashboards show page`: was the API call working or not? Finally, can you clarify what API method you are calling? Is it [users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list) (`service.list_user_labels`)?

Comment: I want to create a user as well as fetch my gmail labels. My first api to create user was working, but the second api(users.labels.list) to fetch labels was giving me error - Google::Apis::ClientError (insufficientPermissions: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.). To fix this issue I added scope in devise.rb - ` https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels` after adding the scope. I started receiving new error - "Invalid credentials" and now neither of my api's are working. I want my both apis to work but not sure what needs to be done.

Comment: edited my question please check

Comment: It's very strange that this error will show up after adding a scope. Are you sure you didn't make any other change? Have you tried following the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby)? Do you get the same behavior?